# Question about mobile app scheme deep linking

Tags: android, ios, mobile, deep-linking, url-scheme

I have the Medium app install on my iPhone.

When doing a search on Google Chrome app, when I clicks on a medium.com link in the search results, it open my Medium app.

How can this happen? How can Google Chrome can interpret https://medium.com to medium://?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the feature in particular you are referring to is Universal Links and requires both server side and client side modifications.

On the server side / website you need to add an AASA (Apple App Site Association) file. This file is simply a JSON file that contains the specific applinks urls for the corresponding app identifier. A sample is shown below.

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [{
      "appID": "ABCDEBBQ.com.medium.ios",
      "paths": ["*"]
    }]
  }
}
```

If you note the paths key in the JSON above you will see that there is a star or wildcard symbol. This simply means open any URL on my websites’ domain. For example www.medium.com/topposts will open in the medium iOS app. It should be noted that you can explicitly define your paths to either include or exclude.

On the client side (Xcode) you’ve gotta setup the associated domains capability inside of your application and specify the applinks service for your domain in this case www.medium.com

Lastly you’ve gotta add the capability to your application identifier inside of the developer portal.

After all of this configuration is completed you should now have a ‘link’ between your website and application.

Apple handles all of this logic internally in iOS and since it’s closed source I cannot give you the exact implementation details but the just of it is that when you visit the domain (medium.com) on your iOS device it downloads the AASA file from the webserver (the AASA file must be hosted on a secure server and can only be downloaded over HTTPS) and the operating system then checks whether there is a corresponding application on the device that matches the appId specified in the AASA file. If both the paths and appIds match it then launches the medium iOS application on the phone.

That’s how it works. I hope that I’ve articulated it well enough.

Comment: Awesome... I couldn't expect a better answer :). Thanks so much!